# Changing time format in an array using moment and angularjs and lodash

Tags: arrays, angularjs, lodash, angular-moment

I have Json data which has timings based on dates.

```
obj = {
"2017-12-08": [
    "2017-12-08T13:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T16:00:00+0530"
],
"2017-12-09": [
    "2017-12-09T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T10:00:00+0530"
],
"2017-12-10": [
    "2017-12-10T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:30:00+0530"
]
}
```

I want to convert this json object into the format below:

```
obj = {
"2017-12-08": ["13:00","15:00","15:30","16:00"],
"2017-12-09": ["09:00","09:30","10:00"],
"2017-12-10": ["09:00","09:30","10:00","10:30"]
}
```

Currently I'm using a for loop to traverse through each element in the array and then replace each element using

```
obj[Object.keys(obj)[date]][time]=moment(obj[Object.keys(obj)[date]][time]).format(HH:mm);
```

how do i accomplish this using lodash , moment and angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`_.forOwn()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forOwn)** to loop over your object properties, **[`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map)** to loop over each `array` items and use `momentjs` to change the item format.

This is how should be your code:

```
_.forOwn(obj, function(value, key) {
   obj[key] = _.map(value, function(item) {
      return moment(item).format("HH:mm");
   });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var obj = {
  "2017-12-08": [
    "2017-12-08T13:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T16:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-09": [
    "2017-12-09T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T10:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-10": [
    "2017-12-10T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:30:00+0530"
  ]
};

_.forOwn(obj, function(value, key) {
  obj[key] = _.map(value, function(item) {
    return moment(item).format("HH:mm");
  });
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You only need momentjs for this, just to format the date in desired format. AngularJS and lodash are not required.

```js
var obj = {
  "2017-12-08": [
    "2017-12-08T13:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T16:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-09": [
    "2017-12-09T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T10:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-10": [
    "2017-12-10T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:30:00+0530"
  ]
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  obj[key] = obj[key].map(item => {
    return moment(item).format("HH:mm");
  });
});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```

This modifies the object in-place. If you don't want that, clone the object first, and then transform the clone.

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `_.mapValues`

```js
const obj = {
  "2017-12-08": [
    "2017-12-08T13:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T15:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-08T16:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-09": [
    "2017-12-09T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-09T10:00:00+0530"
  ],
  "2017-12-10": [
    "2017-12-10T09:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T09:30:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:00:00+0530",
    "2017-12-10T10:30:00+0530"
  ]
};

const res = _.mapValues(obj, el => el.map(d => moment(d).format('HH:mm')));

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.3/moment.min.js"></script>
```